# Customer-editable defaults for .NET plug-in settings

Tags: c#, .net, plugins, configuration

### Short Question:

Is there a way to provide a customer-editable machine-scoped configuration file that will provide defaults for user-scoped settings "buried" inside a plug-in loaded by a third-party application?

### More Details:

- A third-party host application (Autodesk Inventor 2010) loads my `Plugin.dll` which, in turn, references `Other.dll` that contains the "meat" of the plug-in.

  - The `Plugin.dll` is "seen" by the host as an in-process COM server (host's plug-in architecture and API are COM-based).
  - The host application is a mix of native code and CLR 2.0. The `Plugin.dll` and `Other.dll` are CLR 4.0 (so after the plug-in is loaded, both CLR 2.0 and CLR 4.0 coexist within the host application).
- `Other.dll` has its own settings that were designed through the Visual Studio 2010 `Settings.settings` mechanism. All settings are user-scoped (and accessed in code through `Properties.Settings.Default`).
- The `Other.dll` provides a UI for editing the settings, which eventually get saved to: `C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\Autodesk,_Inc\DefaultDomain_Path_0s3njlwv3kl0bcv0w3ply5p1ublvhgsb\Autodesk®_Inventor®_2010\user.config`.

The customer has a number of workstations shared by multiple users and they'd like to be able to provide setting defaults without copying `user.config` to each user's folder. The OS is Windows 7 if that matters.

Is there an elegant way to accomplish this, without abandoning the `Properties.Settings.Default` mechanism?

### Addendum:

The host application's settings are in `C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Inventor 2010\bin\Inventor.exe.config`, but when I try to add defaults there, the host application simply crashes during startup. Could this be due different CLR versions being used together?

For what it's worth, here is the original `Inventor.exe.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- $Header:$ -->
<!-- This config file is copied to the Inventor bin\ folder by //inventor/Main/Sources/AddInApps/ContentCenter/_RootBuildInventor/PostBuild.bat -->
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="autodesk.inventor.content">
            <section name="logging" type="System.Configuration.DictionarySectionHandler,system, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, Custom=null"/>
    </sectionGroup>
    <section name="microsoft.web.services3" type="Microsoft.Web.Services3.Configuration.WebServicesConfiguration, Microsoft.Web.Services3, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </configSections>
    <appSettings>
        <!-- Controls client cache allocation limit. MaxCachedObjects controls the maximum number
             of cached objects before a purge is done. CachePurgeInterval controls how many objects
             are removed when a purge is done -->
        <add key="Connectivity.Content.MaxCachedObjects" value="500"/>
        <add key="Connectivity.Content.CachePurgeInterval" value="100"/>
        <add key="Connectivity.Content.MaxSearchResults" value="2500"/>
        <!-- WebService timeout (in milliseconds)-->
        <add key="WebServiceTimeout" value="1000000"/>
    </appSettings>
  <microsoft.web.services3>
    <messaging>
      <maxMessageLength value="51200"/>
      <mtom clientMode="On" maxMimeParts="1024"/>
    </messaging>
    <security>
      <!-- Specifies the time buffer used by WSE to determine when a SOAP message is valid.
           set to the max of 24hr in seconds -->
      <timeToleranceInSeconds value="86400" />
    </security>
  </microsoft.web.services3>
    <!-- Since Inventor is an unmanaged application, we need to explicitly identify
         the framework version it's to use. Otherwise, it will pick up the latest
         version that's been installed -->
    <startup>
    <!-- The following specification works for both .NET 2.0 and .NET 3.0, since they share the same CLR.
         .NET 3.0 installs both 
             C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727 (the CLR) and
             C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0
         The 'v3.0' folder contains WPF and some other components built on top of .NET 2.0.
         Inventor won't start up if the following in changed to "V3.0" -->
        <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

And here is the one I modified that is causing the crash:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- $Header:$ -->
<!-- This config file is copied to the Inventor bin\ folder by //inventor/Main/Sources/AddInApps/ContentCenter/_RootBuildInventor/PostBuild.bat -->
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="autodesk.inventor.content">
            <section name="logging" type="System.Configuration.DictionarySectionHandler,system, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, Custom=null"/>
        </sectionGroup>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="Etrage.Ifs.CadAddin.Common.Ui.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    <section name="microsoft.web.services3" type="Microsoft.Web.Services3.Configuration.WebServicesConfiguration, Microsoft.Web.Services3, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </configSections>
    <appSettings>
        <!-- Controls client cache allocation limit. MaxCachedObjects controls the maximum number
             of cached objects before a purge is done. CachePurgeInterval controls how many objects
             are removed when a purge is done -->
        <add key="Connectivity.Content.MaxCachedObjects" value="500"/>
        <add key="Connectivity.Content.CachePurgeInterval" value="100"/>
        <add key="Connectivity.Content.MaxSearchResults" value="2500"/>
        <!-- WebService timeout (in milliseconds)-->
        <add key="WebServiceTimeout" value="1000000"/>
    </appSettings>

    <userSettings>
        <Etrage.Ifs.CadAddin.Inventor.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="MapiPropertiesToIfsPart" serializeAs="String">
                <value>False</value>
            </setting>
        </Etrage.Ifs.CadAddin.Inventor.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>

    <microsoft.web.services3>
    <messaging>
      <maxMessageLength value="51200"/>
      <mtom clientMode="On" maxMimeParts="1024"/>
    </messaging>
    <security>
      <!-- Specifies the time buffer used by WSE to determine when a SOAP message is valid.
           set to the max of 24hr in seconds -->
      <timeToleranceInSeconds value="86400" />
    </security>
  </microsoft.web.services3>
    <!-- Since Inventor is an unmanaged application, we need to explicitly identify
         the framework version it's to use. Otherwise, it will pick up the latest
         version that's been installed -->
    <startup>
    <!-- The following specification works for both .NET 2.0 and .NET 3.0, since they share the same CLR.
         .NET 3.0 installs both 
             C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727 (the CLR) and
             C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0
         The 'v3.0' folder contains WPF and some other components built on top of .NET 2.0.
         Inventor won't start up if the following in changed to "V3.0" -->
        <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Did you arrive to any solution?